# ubuntu 22.04 LTS in UTM on MAC M1 is glitching very badly

Tags: 22.04, virtualization, display-resolution, mac, tearing

I very recently downloaded UTM and installed ubuntu 22.04 in it. And at first i was facing some black screen issues but later i changed the emulated display card and it was working fine. but ubuntu is glitching when i try to drag or move the opened applications and the resolution is poor, not as smooth as other users says. how can i get it to work smoothly?

Comment: I don't know how to solve this problem, but you can run Asahi Linux (natively) on a M1 Mac https://asahilinux.org/. It supports the GPU as of last December, and should not have any such resolution issues.

Answer (score 5):

I successfully installed 22.04 LTS on my MacBook Pro 14" 2022
Here are the steps I've followed:

1. Download the following ISO from a non-public link. This image is the arm64 version (M chips are ARM architectures) of 22.04 -> https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/jammy/daily-live/current/jammy-desktop-arm64.iso
2. Download UTM to create a virtual machine.
3. When creating the VM, please choose: virtualize -> Linux.
4. Select the iso image and finish the creation steps.
5. At this point, you will run a desktop version where you can use Ubuntu and install it from a user interface. Follow the regular steps to install.
6. When requesting to reboot. Instead, shutdown the VM and eject or clear the ISO image from the virtual drive of the VM.
7. Run the VM and you should be ok with a fresh ubuntu install!

Tips:

- Select the `virtio-ramfb` emulated graphics cards. It's the best one I've used. But I'm not 100% sure why
- You can `Force Multicore` in order to use the full resources of your beast chipset.

Hope it helps!